# Jabber notifier plugin cannot send messages

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, xmpp, jenkins-plugins

I'd like to be notified whenever one of my automated tests is not working so that's why I'm using Jenkins with Jabber (XMPP) notifier plugin.
Currently it is not possible to send any notifications and I'm getting the following output:

Jabber notifier plugin: Sending notification to: test@jabber.de
Jabber notifier plugin: [ERROR] not connected. Cannot send message to 'test@jabber.de'

Please see the configuration on Jenkins below:
[image]

And this is what I received from the log file (jenkins.log):

```
2019-10-16 11:47:36.607+0000 [id=35]    INFO    h.p.j.i.t.JabberIMConnection#initNewConnection: Connected to XMPP on 192.168.1.3:5222/jabber.hamburg.de using secure connection
2019-10-16 11:47:36.608+0000 [id=35]    WARNING h.p.j.i.t.JabberIMConnection#connect: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringprepException: XmppStringprepException caused by '': org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringprepException: Argument can't be the empty string
    at org.jxmpp.jid.impl.JidCreate.entityBareFromUnescapedOrThrowUnchecked(JidCreate.java:695)
    at hudson.plugins.jabber.im.transport.JabberIMConnection.getOrCreateGroupChat(JabberIMConnection.java:628)
    at hudson.plugins.jabber.im.transport.JabberIMConnection.initNewConnection(JabberIMConnection.java:270)
    at hudson.plugins.jabber.im.transport.JabberIMConnection.connect(JabberIMConnection.java:232)
    at hudson.plugins.jabber.im.transport.JabberIMConnectionProvider.createConnection(JabberIMConnectionProvider.java:75)
    at hudson.plugins.im.IMConnectionProvider.create(IMConnectionProvider.java:59)
    at hudson.plugins.im.IMConnectionProvider.access$500(IMConnectionProvider.java:16)
    at hudson.plugins.im.IMConnectionProvider$ConnectorRunnable.run(IMConnectionProvider.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringprepException: XmppStringprepException caused by '': org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringprepException: Argument can't be the empty string
    at org.jxmpp.jid.impl.JidCreate.entityBareFromUnescaped(JidCreate.java:731)
    at org.jxmpp.jid.impl.JidCreate.entityBareFromUnescaped(JidCreate.java:707)
    at org.jxmpp.jid.impl.JidCreate.entityBareFromUnescapedOrThrowUnchecked(JidCreate.java:693)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringprepException: Argument can't be the empty string
    at org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringPrepUtil.throwIfEmptyString(XmppStringPrepUtil.java:131)
    at org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringPrepUtil.domainprep(XmppStringPrepUtil.java:79)
    at org.jxmpp.jid.parts.Domainpart.from(Domainpart.java:90)
    at org.jxmpp.jid.impl.DomainpartJid.<init>(DomainpartJid.java:41)
    at org.jxmpp.jid.impl.LocalAndDomainpartJid.<init>(LocalAndDomainpartJid.java:45)
    at org.jxmpp.jid.impl.JidCreate.entityBareFromUnescaped(JidCreate.java:729)
    ... 10 more
```

I'll be greatful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading the version of the Jabber plugin from 1.37 to 1.36 solved the issue.